# PHP first sends data to database then validates

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation, email

I'm having a problem with email validation.

The email validation is working but it first sends the form and if I refresh the page and send the same data again then it validates. 
Why doesn't it validate before it's been send?

My Code:

```
<?php
include_once 'init.inc.php';

// database connection

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// function for Registration

function regUser($db)
{
 $password = password_hash($_POST['password3'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users SET username = '{$_POST['username']}', email = '{$_POST['email']}', password = '$password', laender = '{$_POST['selection']}'";
 $result = $db->query($sql);
 return $result;
}

// function for emailValidation

function emailValidate()
{
 $email1 = $_POST['email'];
 $email1 = filter_var($email1, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 if (!filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

// function to check if username already registered

function usernameExists($db)
{
 $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
 $result = $db->query($sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

// function to check if email already exists in database

function emailExists($db)
{

 // var_dump(emailExists($db));

 $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '" . $_POST['email'] . "'";
 $result = $db->query($sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

// sending data to database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 // var_dump(usernameExists($db));
 // var_dump(emailExists($db));

 if (emailValidate() === false)
 {
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Please enter a valid email adress';
 }

 if (usernameExists($db) === false && emailExists($db) === false)
 {
  regUser($db);
 }
 else
 {
  die("Username / Email already exists!");
 }
}
```

The Username and Email exists function is working fine. 
Only the email validation is validating after the form is submitted.

Comment: I see many things to be improved in this code of yours, bu tell me. Are there any errors being displayed?

Comment: no errors being displayed, it validates fine but only after it has been send to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to re-order some of your condition checking code so that you check for the existence of email/username in the database **ONLY** after the email itself is valid:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // email address is not valid, show error message
    if (emailValidate() !== false)
    {
        echo 'Please enter a valid email adress';
    }
    // email address is valid. Now check if it exists in the DB
    else
    {
        if ( (usernameExists($db) === false) && (emailExists($db) === false))
        {
            regUser($db);
        }
        else
        {
            // you can also use echo error in place of die() here
            die("Username / Email already exists!");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
if(emailValidate() === false){

}else {
    die( 'Please enter a valid email adress');//use die while not echo, otherwise the php will keep on running even the email is wrong

}
```

Also, you can do this:

```
if(emailValidate() !== false){
    die( 'Please enter a valid email adress');
}
```

Comment: it works with die(); but how can i display the error in html directly under the emails input? because with die(); it opens a new page :/